# Why is lead(II) present in two groups of cation analysis?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

Well, I found that lead cation $\ce{Pb^2+}$ is present in both group 1 and group 2 of cation analysis. But why?

Answer (score 10):

Simply because lead(II) fits both analytical groups:

- it forms [lead(II) chloride $\ce{PbCl2}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II)_chloride), a poor soluble chloride, which puts it in the [1st group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualitative_inorganic_analysis#1st_analytical_group_of_cations);
- it also forms [lead(II) sulfide $\ce{PbS}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II)_sulfide), insoluble in water and diluted acids, which also puts it in the [2nd group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualitative_inorganic_analysis#2nd_analytical_group_of_cations).

One reason for putting lead in both groups is that the chloride is somewhat of a borderline case in terms of being insoluble enough to appear in Group I.  Group II represents a more complicated analysis but is more sensitive for lead.

Comment: Lead (II) chloride has enough solubility so it could slip through the cracks in Group I.  Group II where the sulfide is precipitated is more sensitive.

Comment: @OscarLanzi You are right, probably it would be worth adding that there are no sharp margins between these 6 groups and various sources add or remove cations 
 from one group to another arbitrarily.

Comment: @andselisk If the product of the $\text{Group I}$ test is $\ce{PbCl2}$ then how can we test for it in $\text{Group I}$?